# controlling "current directory" in which subprocess is executed in racket

Tags: process, racket

Is it possible to control the current working directory of a process spawned with `subprocess`, in racket?
I mean: if I run something like that:

```
(define-values (p sout sin serr) (subprocess #f #f #f "myscript.sh"))
```

is there a way to control the working directory in which `myscript.sh`is executed? (If I knew a method, I would test it running `"/bin/pwd"` instead of `"myscript.sh"`, and then checking what comes out of `sout`...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `current-directory` parameter:

```
(define-values (p sout sin serr)
  (parameterize ([current-directory "/some/where"])
    (subprocess #f #f #f "myscript.sh")))
```